# How to escape a shill directorship

Tags: united-kingdom, quitting

I have been working for a company for a little over 6 years. Around 18 months ago the director approached me with a proposal. He was launching a sister company to do much the same thing but in some different territories and wanted me to be a director of the sister company.

I won't go into too much detail, but the bottom line is that this is a shill company, and that realisation unfortunately only became clear to me after some time.

Now a year on, the company seems to be going strong, but I've had absolutely no input into it, I have very little information about what it's doing, and I am the only director of the company.

I realise I have left myself in a position where I could be screwed and I am now feeling uncomfortable about it and want out.

To that end, I have started looking for another job. I don't feel like it would be possible to close the company and keep my job, everything would be messy and awkward and it's much easier for everyone if I just make a clean break.

However, the timing will be critical as I can't afford to be without a job for more than a few weeks and I also don't want to give them any opportunity to cause me financial trouble by leaving me with a company with debts on my hands.

My question is this: I know I've made a mistake in letting myself get suckered into this, how do I make a clean break without any undue risk to myself financially or legally?

Note: I'm not interested in getting anyone into any trouble financially or legally, and would prefer everyone to be happy at the end, but if it comes down to a choice I will obviously put myself first.

Note 2: There is no formal contract in place covering this relationship between me and the company and my employer other than a standard terms of employment contract. I was verbally offered a fixed payment and this was simply added to my salary.

Comment: What exactly does companieshouse think your position is? If they think you are the director then you may be in trouble.

Comment: @gnasher729 I am the director, registered at companies house

Comment: Personally I think this is a "lawyer up now" situation.  You are effectively part of a fraudulent scheme, albeit naively.

Comment: Your question is confusing - you seem to assume that the company would shut down without you, but also state that you are not involved. It seems like your role is not critical so leaving would not impair the company. Also, you imply that you might be personally liable but as an employee that would be virtually impossible. How would you end up owning it or being responsible for it in any way? Last, you feel you could be "screwed" but it isn't clear how that could happen... illegal activities usually require you to be aware of the activity at a minimum.

Comment: @Jim The OPs boss seems to be using the OPs name for his own benefit.  That could be for a whole range of nefarious purposes that the OP isn't aware of. EG hiding income, making the OP a fall guy etc.  While not necessary illegal the OPs boss is up to no good and could cause the OP a world of hurt if the OP exposes it.

Comment: Shill or shell?

Comment: "Companies House is the United Kingdom's registrar of companies", per Wikipedia, so the above comment "I am the director, registered at companies house" sounds like OP is legally registered as being in charge of the company.

Comment: As it is a limited liability company, creditors could only claim company assets, and never your own, no matter what happens, so you are safe financially. However, that might change if they can prove fraud, so get lawyered up ASAP. You will find that most will give you a free hour of consultation, and their is also the Citizens' Advice Centre.

Comment: @Mawg Incorrect. Under certain circumstances, directors can become personally liable for company debts. See e.g. https://www.russell-cooke.co.uk/news-insight/briefings/2010/personal-liability-for-directors/ "Whilst the principle of separate legal personality is still the cornerstone of English company law, there are numerous ways in which even directors who are not guilty of genuine wrongdoing may end up being personally liable, directly or indirectly, for the debts and other obligations of the company."

Comment: Then let's hope that the OP is "not guilty of genuine wrongdoing"; but he certainly needs to get legal advice ASAP. Perhaps https://law.stackexchange.com/ could offer advice?

Comment: @Confused While the process of ending a directorship is likely in scope for this SE, the "without any undue risk to myself" angle of things makes the only right answer be talk to your lawyer.  Without seeing the specific documents you signed we could be missing pieces of the puzzle and lead to advice that makes your situation worse.  Don't delay, don't go to the Law SE, go to your lawyer ASAP.

Comment: @Confused This is especially important if you think that you are being set up to take the fall.  If this was the plan of the original company director the whole time it may be structured in such a way that it's complicated to extract yourself from the situation.

Comment: @Mawg If he is registered as the company director then he is fully legally responsible for everything the company does.

Comment: Then, as I replied to Philip above, he certainly needs to get legal advice ASAP

Answer (score 7):

> I have very little information about what it's doing, and I am the only director of the company.

As I hope you realise now, this was a serious mistake to make. As a director of a company, you are expected to "exercise reasonable care, skill and diligence" (from the Companies Act 2006). It seems likely that you have not done that, which *could* (talk to an actual lawyer) make you personally liable for the actions of the company.

> I know I've made a mistake in letting myself get suckered into this, how do I make a clean break without any undue risk to myself financially or legally?

You resign as a director. The forms are available from Companies House. Note that this doesn't result in the company closing, simply that the shareholders (whoever they may be) are required to appoint another director.

> There is no formal contract in place covering this relationship between me and the company

While there's not a contract, there's something from your point of view much more serious than that: your directorship. There were a whole bunch of forms you signed when you became a director in which you asserted that you understood the responsibilities that you were taking on; that's going to make the courts look unfavourably on any claims of "I didn't understand what was going on".

I seriously advise you to go and talk to a actual lawyer as they will be able to advise you how best to get out of the very large hole you've dug for yourself here.